# How to run script from imported file using gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am importing a template yml from a commmon library. The template calls a function extractText.js, the function fails to run because it is expecting the function to be in the root folder of the project that is importing the gitlab-ci.yml file.

The script works if i have the extractText.js file in the root folder of the project.

How can i make it so that i don't need to add extractText.js file to each project that imports the template.

### gitlab-ci.yml file

```
include:
  - project: 'common-library'
    ref: 'branch-123'
    file:
     - 'templates/gitlab-ci.yml'
```

### test section

```
test:
    stage: test   
    before_script:
      - npm ci
    script:
      - npm test
    after_script:      
      - export Text=$(node extractText.js)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to put your functionality into an own Docker image and execute it as an own step.

Benefits:

1. you can't be sure that the requirements will be met by the including repository. Maybe Node version needed is different etc.
2. if you run it as an own step, depending on your structure you can easily apply it if you for example need it also for other steps by forwarding the needed resources.

It is quiet hard to give a really good suggestion, as the motivation is missing, what happens with this `Text` afterwards.

Also depending on the functionality of `extractText.js` you might want to just use a shell script, which will work out of the box in any kind of container, if it is really just some kind of extraction.